# Make [flux] a synonym for [f.lux]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tag-synonym-request

For those who haven't never heard of [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) before, here's a brief description [via Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F.lux).

> f.lux is a cross-platform computer program that adjusts a display's
>   color temperature according to location and time of day. The program
>   was designed to reduce eye strain during night-time use and reduce
>   disruption of sleep patterns.

I propose adding [flux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/flux) as a synonym for [f.lux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/f.lux). While it's not a particularly popular tag, it does have a few questions. Intuitively, most people asking questions wouldn't think to try using the f.lux tag unless they specifically remembered the program's bizarre spelling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

F.lux has a rather specific spelling and there are other [softwares](http://www.cedrat.com/software/flux/) that might use the non mangled name.

I'd much rather prevent use of the vague generic spelling and prefer the special spelling [f.lux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/f.lux) or manufacturer product style of [cedrat-flux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cedrat-flux) (as would be the case with the random software I found).

I don't think the synonym is relevant in this case, it doesn't fit the actual product name and is too generic.